# HTML in Long Description of SPFx Package-Solution

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

According to the [schema](https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json) for a SPFx `package-solution`, the `longDescription`, which is located under `metadadata` should accept HTML. I have been able to put newline characters (using `\n`) but not HTML.

Anybody had any luck using HTML?

Comment: Nope, never tried and there's never a need to do it, at least in my case.